# Pack and Distribute an Ant Project

Tags: java, ant, build, packaging

I have an Ant project build in NetBeans, as a Java Free-Form Project. What I want to do is to pack  the project and dristribute it just to execute a .bat and run the application, but the project uses SunSpot, etc.

To sum up, If I create a .bat (whose single line is "ant") in the root directory of my project (where is the folder src, the file build.xml, etc.) and run it, everything is alright. But I don't want to pass to a client a NetBeans project folder and a .bat, I would like to pass him just a .jar and a .bat

How could I do all these?? If it's from the build.xml while compiling, even better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following reading:

- [Packaging program in jar files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/)
- [ANT tutorials](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorials.html)